# Spinner values vs text?

Tags: android

Imagine an app that has a spinner menu with values 1,2,3,4 etc, but in text. In HTML you'd specify both the value, and the displayed text:

1 One

2 Two

3 Three

etc, and you can then make the interface pleasing to users, but easy for the app to extract the value (e.g. 3, not Three)

I need a drop-down menu in an Android app that shows text equivalents of numeric values. How do I display the right text, but then easily extract the right value behind it? I don't want to use the position, as that is prone to bugs if the contents are changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create two List object one contain the display value and another contain the actual value for e.g.

```
List<String> disp_list = new ArrayList<String>();

disp_list contains [one, two, three]

List<String> actual_list = new ArrayList<String>();

actual_list contains [1,2,3]
```

now when user select get the position value on change listener of spinner and get the actual value form the actual_list

select in spinner is "two" and it's index value is 1;

```
String sel = "";
```

for e.g.

```
spinner.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int index, long position) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
     sel = actual_list.get(index);
}
});
```